# Can't get videojs on listener when using Underscore _.bind

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, video.js

This is how I got it to work but I don't like how it looks. I really want to make it work using _.bind

```
displayVideo: function displayVideo() {
  let _this = this;
  this.videoJs = videojs('player', {}, function () {
    this.on('play', _this.onPlayerPlayButton);
    this.on('pause', _this.onPlayerPauseButton);
  });
},
```

The .on event listener wasn't working when I wrote it like this

```
displayVideo: function displayVideo() {
  this.videoJs = videojs('player', {}, _.bind(function () {
    this.on('play', this.onPlayerPlayButton);
    this.on('pause', this.onPlayerPauseButton);
  }, this));
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sample from underscore library.

```
var func = function(greeting){ return greeting + ': ' + this.name };
func = _.bind(func, {name: 'moe'}, 'hi');
func();
```

This sample is working. The function is being binded to this (the caller of displayVideo method of your object)

Try this sample from the page of underscore in the page of underscore http://underscorejs.org/ so you see how it works.

It will call the func function and say 'Hi' args of this name where this is the second argument of your _.bind underscore function, the object {name: 'Moe'}

Comment: I cannot give you a working sample with the code you share because it is hard to see who is the caller of your method displayVideo, so i can not be sure if the scope will be right for your case.

Comment: It's ok, I got it working like this let vid = this;
      vid.on('play', _.bind(self. onPlayerPlayButton, self)); inside the promise then i have let self = this outside